# Japanese equivalent of "caught red handed"?

Tags: slang, colloquial-language, phrases, phrase-requests

Is there a colloquial phrase in Japanese that would be the same as or similar in meaning to the English phrase "caught red handed"?

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic part "red-handed" can be translated with 現行犯(で).

For "catch" you use an appropriate form of 捕まる・捕える or 逮捕（する） or 取り押さえる.

For example,

> 被疑者を現行犯で逮捕した。
>   We caught the suspect red-handed.

There also appears to be a compound noun 現行犯逮捕（する） for "being caught in the act / red-handed".

Comment: +1. Note that this expression isn't figurative (unlike *red-handed*) nor specifically colloquial (it can be used both in colloquial and rather formal contexts). It's quite common, though, and I don't come up with any other phrases.