# Being caught in an act?

Tags: translation, word-requests, english-to-japanese

What would be the proper way to phrase such an action, particularly in a casual way? Say, the phrase “Oh, I guess you caught me.” How might a native speaker say this? I know in a criminal context of someone being caught in an act, a sentence like “被疑者を現行犯で逮捕した。” but I need a less specific way to put it.

Comment: 100％自然な日本語を探してるなら「み」で始まるあのフレーズやろな。より口語的にはその「み」が「め」に変わるっちゅう・・

Comment: Related, for anyone interested:  [Japanese equivalent of “caught red handed”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48297/78)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps バレる is the word you're looking for?

"Oh, I guess you caught me." -> 「あぁ、**バレて**しまったな」